# Should I use a static class for global variables or just use static properties?

Tags: c#

I'm building a class to hold some global variables.

I'm just curios what would make the diference in using a static or a non-static class for this purpose.

Example

```
    public class Modules
    {
        public static int Modul1{ get { return 1; } }
    }
```

or

```
    public static class Modules
    {
        public static int Modul1{ get { return 1; } }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declaring like a static you add at least 2 architectual restrictions :

1) None can derive from that class and extend it in any way.

2) Internal members can be only static ones.

So if you want to use this class like a config base, use it like a static class definitely.

Answer (score 1):

The difference is that you cannot create an instance from a static class. If you are not going to use the class for objects that is the best option so its clear that this class shouldn't be instantiated.

Edit:
As a sidenote, i think it's bad design to do this in large projects: [link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/scottdensmore/archive/2004/05/25/140827.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I have a static Settings class with static properties, seemed to make sense, no need to create multiple instances and a singleton seemed overkill.

Answer (score 0):

In instance classes, you can have mix of static and non static. But in static class, every ting is static. So no instance specific members can reside.

Plus if all on the purpose or needs, do you really require the whole class to be static than just the member of it?